# Showing Exception While opening FolderBrowser

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to select the path,so i am using Folderbrowser dialog.But its showing exception at the line "DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();"Exception is

```
      Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the process.
```

public void OpenFolder()
  {

```
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
         DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            Folderpath = fbd.SelectedPath;

        }
```

}

Comment: The exception message specifically tells you to look at your Main() method.  Seems you didn't look, we can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the [STAThreadAttribute] attribute above the main method

```
[STAThreadAttribute]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        OpenFolder();
    }
```